# Job runs again automatically

Tags: spring-batch

This is what I've encountered. The job was successfully run but then it runs again with different jobid.

Does anyone encountered this before?

Appreciate your help

Comment: have you scheduled it to run periodically?

Comment: @Anirudh Simha, no it doesn't. I run it manually

Comment: Please explain how do you trigger job execution. Do you have persistent database?

Comment: I run the job through mvn and the jobname is parameterized. Yes I do, I'm using this for conversion of specific column

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using @Qualifier when defining my step in job builder factory.

Thanks